# Retrieve unique data from table column and sorting array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is one table , and I want the unique values of table column data, like table row may have 4, 2 , 2, 4,5 , 4. So it should return array like this `data = [ 2 , 4 , 5 ]`

I am able to achieve this using jquery as below link

http://jsbin.com/ojeroc/5/edit#source

But data should come in ascending order So I can use this array in another function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("document is ready");          
    var items=[], options=[];
    console.log(items);
    console.log(options);
    //Iterate all td's in second column
    $('#dataTable tr  td').each( function(){
    //console.log("Inside tr data");                                                                                                         
       //add item to array
       items.push( $(this).text() );       
      // console.log($(this).text());
    });
    //restrict array to unique items
    var items = $.unique( items );
    alert(items);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method to sort array items:

```
var sortedItems = $.unique( items ).sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
});
```

The function passed as parameter is used to compare two items in the array. It receives two elements.

The sorting is done by returning a negative/positive/zero number. To compare numbers, you can then simply substract b from a.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/M7QZS/)**

Comment: Thanks, I want to retrieve minimum and maximum values  of the sorted array , can that be done?

Comment: @Wazdesign If you think for a second, you will see it is easy.

Comment: After the sort, `sortedItems[0]` will get you the min and `sortedItems[sortedItems.length-1]` the max.

Answer (score 2):

```
function sortNumber(a,b)
{
      return a - b;
}

var n = ["10", "5", "40", "25", "100", "1"];
document.write(n.sort(sortNumber));
```

would create this output:

> 1,5,10,25,40,100

You could also wrap it in an anonymous function

```
n.sort(function(a,b){return a-b;})
```

Which would be faster, but if you need to use it over and over again, I would stick with the function.

Comment: Hope it was helpful for you ;-)